# How can i store more than one product_ticket?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Im trying to store more than one product with my controller. In my function store first i generate a ticket and then i generate a product_ticket with the ticket_id recently generated and the product_id from the selected product from the form. But how can i do to store more than one if i select more than one product in the form.

This are my relationships:

Product.php:

```
 class Product extends Model
{

  public function tickets()
  {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Ticket::class);
  }


  public function productXticket()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(ProductXTicket::class);    

  }

 }
```

Ticket.php

```
    class Ticket extends Model
{
public function productXticket()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductXTicket::class);    

   }


    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
  }
```

ProductXTicket:

```
    class ProductXTicket extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product_ticket';

    public function ticket_id(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Ticket::class);
   }

    public function product_id(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

product_ticket migration:

```
Schema::create('product_ticket', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('ticket_id')->constrained();
        $table->string('serial_number');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->timestamps();
       });
    }

TicketController:

        public function store(Request $request){
       /*dd($request->all());*/

        $ticket = new Ticket();
    
        /*$ticket->cuenta_id = $request->cuenta_id;*/
        $ticket->contact_id = $request->contact_id;
        $ticket->statusTicket_id = $request->statusTicket_id;
        $ticket->typeTicket_id = $request->typeTicket_id;
        $ticket->idOwner = Auth::user()->id;     

        $ticket->save();
        $productXticket = new ProductXTicket();
        $productXticket->ticket_id = $ticket->id;
        $productXticket->serial_number = $request->serial_number;
        $productXticket->quantity = $request->quantity;

        $ticket->productXticket()->save($productXticket);
        Session::flash('success');
        return redirect()->route('tickets.view');
     }
```

So here im storing one ticket and one product_ticket. I want form each ticket to store the same amount of product_ticket as the amount products selected

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
$ticket->productXticket()->save($productXticket);
```

Use:

```
$ticket->productXticket()->saveMany([$productXticket,...]);
```